# remove UIImageView from subview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I created UIImageViews and add it to subview. Then I add it to NSMutableArray.

So, I need delete from memory and subview object(UIImageView) in some index

```
[arr removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

and

```
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
```

don't help, because UIImageView doesn't disappear from View.

How to do this?

sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[arr objectAtIndex:index] removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer to add them to array, just give items tag value

```
[imageview setTag:index++];
```

. And you can get views with

```
[self viewWithTag:index];
```

and remove them

```
[[self viewWithTag:index] removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: so, i can write `UIImageView *imageview = [...]; [imageview setTag:index++]; imageview = [...]; [imageview setTag:index++];` ?

Comment: yes, ofcorse. But you can use specific indexes for imageviews. İt might confuse for other views so use something like [imageview setTag:MY_VIEWS+index++];